# First word in the table is not splitted appropriately

Tags: tables

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}}
\hline
Column1 & Column2 & LongName ofColumn3
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And I'm wondering how can I fir the text in the third column to the width of the column, i.e. split the words in such a way that they don't go outside table.

[image]

**EDIT**: the following works fine but now I would like to know how can I split the text in column2 "Line1 Line2" into two lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\newcolumntype{v}{|}


\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{vL{1.3}vC{1.3}vC{0.4}}
\hline
Column1 & Line1 Line2 & LongName of Column3
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the full width of a table is almost always more than just `\textwidth` because you need to take into account the padding inside the cells. Using `tabularx`, why don't you use the `X` column type? Apar from that, LaTeX may have difficulties to hyphenate words that are not proper English (or whatever language you choose).

Comment: thanks, could you please look at my edited question? I would like to split the column name into two separate lines

Comment: Text splitting in column 2: `Line1\\linebreak Line2`. BTW, `LongName` is longer than the column width of column 3.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)